# What is the type for addeventlistener if an attribute of the element changes?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Hi,

I have this code:

```
<div id="container" data-room="room1"></div>
```

I want to add a listener so a function triggers when the data in `data-room` changes but I dont know what type to use in this case. I tried onchange

```
container.addEventListener('onchange', function(e) {
```

but seems like its only good for checkboxes and so. What type should I use here?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener

Comment: is DOM4 Mutation Observers the latest update?

Comment: [Here's the latest documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: quick question, does it work also if I change the value on the developer tools console? Because im not getting anything when testing it there.

Comment: I actually don't know. I've never used it before. Sorry.

Comment: seems like it wont.